# Double parse with culture format

Tags: c#, int32

I have a double number as string. The number is

> 202.667,40

Which is 202667.4

How can I parse this string to get the value like: Double.Parse("202.667,40",?what here), or any other method to get the value would be great. Thanks

Comment: Use the CultureInfo of a culture that uses a comma as a decimal point. Germany for example.  Preferably matching whatever country the string came from.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First, you need to know which culture this number is from, then:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("de"); // I'm assuming german here.
double number = Double.Parse("202.667,40", culture);
```

If you want to parse using the current thread culture, which by default is the one set for the current user:

```
double number = Double.Parse("202.667,40", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Using "de" causes a NotSupportedException to get thrown for me.

"Culture 'de' is a neutral culture. It cannot be used in formatting and parsing and therefore cannot be set as the thread's current culture."

Perhaps you wanted "de-DE"?

Answer (score 11):

I think i have found a solution which does not require a culture. Using a NumberFormatInfo you can force a format, no matter the culture:

```
// This is invariant
NumberFormatInfo format = new NumberFormatInfo();
// Set the 'splitter' for thousands
format.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
// Set the decimal seperator
format.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
```

Then later:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(double.Parse("202.667,40", format)));
```

Outputs:
202667,4

Of course, this *output* (inner toString()) might differ per Culture(!)
Note that changing the input to "202,667.40" will result in a parse error, so the format should match your expected input.

Hope this helps someone..

Answer (score 3):

You could use Double.Parse(your_number, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) and set CurrentCulture accordingly with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.

Example:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
```

then later

```
Double.Parse(your_number, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Note that if you explicitly assign the culture to the CurrentThread, it only applies to that thread.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having to specify a locale in all parses, I prefer to set an application wide locale, although if string formats are not consistent across the app, this might not work.

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-PT");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("pt-PT");
```

Defining this at the begining of your application will make all double parses expect a comma as the decimal delimiter.

Comment: I had big issue in xamarin. This is work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For more flexibility you can set NumberDecimalSeparator

```
string number = "202.667,40";
double.Parse(number.Replace(".", ""), new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name) {NumberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo() {NumberDecimalSeparator = ","}});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var val=double.Parse( yourValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

http://www.erikschierboom.com/2014/09/01/numbers-and-culture/

Answer (score 1):

```
Double.Parse("202.667,40", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Instead of de-DE use whatever culture the string is in.