# Detecting culture info from a string which has numeric value

Tags: c#, globalization, cultureinfo

Here is a **List< string > lstA**;

**lstA** may contains value(datatype **string**) like:
**1st example**

> 1
>
> 1.00
>
> 1000.01
>
> 1,002.98
>
> .........

Or **listA** may contain value like: **2nd example**

> 1
>
> 1,00
>
> 1000,01
>
> 1.002,98
>
> .........

i am trying to pass this list to a method and it will return me a string "german" or "us"

I am trying this:

```
private static string ReturnCulture(List<string> lst)
    {
        string cull = "";
        foreach (string s in lst)
        {
            if (s.Contains(".") && s.Contains(","))
            {
                cull = "german";
                break;
            }
            else if (!s.Contains(".") && s.Contains(","))
            {
                cull = "german";
            }
            else if (s.Contains(".") && !s.Contains(","))
            {
                cull = "us";
                break;
            }
            else if (!s.Contains(".") && !s.Contains(","))
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        return cull;
    }
```

this works fine as for first 3 value. but when i get (**1,002.98**) or ("1.002,98") this both fullfils for german condition.

How to solve this? can globalization class easily detect which culture it is? the given example of **lstA** is realy random. but it will be either as **1st example** or the **2nd**.

Comment: What happens when you get two cultures that share some of the same symbols?

Comment: i have to think about two symbols here "." and ",". In my last 5th line i cleared the scene which i worried about.

Comment: What is your final goal? Why do you need to parse numbers to culture?

Comment: i have to do some calculations with the values of this list and i have to do this in german format. but input is not always in german.

Comment: So, i'd suggest you to change your post to "how can I parse numbers from different cultures" - because when you will receive invariant numbers, you can easaly format them to german.

Comment: can i change my title now?

Comment: His issue though is that he doesn't know the culture. He seems to know that it's either german or us, but he can't tell for sure. And on a value such as `1.000`, you can't say which it is for certain. `1.000` is a valid number in both cultures, but have different actual values in each. 

I might suggest using `Double.TryParse` with a german culture and a us culture. Then if only one of them works, you can use that one. If both work.... well you're going to have to pick a default...

Comment: @user1865670 yes, you can change the title or edit your post. Did you try to use double.parse?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parse numbers of only several cultures, may be you'll find usefull using double.parse with culture format parameter. See [Double parse with culture format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109816/double-parse-with-culture-format)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot definitively create a method that given a set of strings will be able to tell you whether the strings are formatted as English or German. You can write a method that will tell you whether all the strings can be parsed as English or German. Since you expect parsing failures, you should use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) as in:

```
private static bool AreAllStringsValidNumberRepresenationsForCulture(CultureInfo ci, List<string> lst)
{
    foreach (string s in lst)
    {
        double number;
        if (!Double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, ci, out number)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It's always better to take explicit input instead of relying on a heuristic, so if there is any way to force a standard number representation, you'd be better off.

Answer (score 0):

You can try parsing them using both culture,

Eg,

```
public static string GetCulture(this string value)
{
    var doubleValue = default(double);
    var germanCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
    var englishCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    if (double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, germanCultureInfo, out doubleValue))
    {
        return "german";
    }
    else if (double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, englishCultureInfo, out doubleValue))
    {
       return "us";
    }
    return string.Empty; ;
}
```