# Convert string to double using special separators

Tags: c#, double

I can't figure out how to do the following :

I want to import some data from a file, including numeric values. The user can personalize separators, which are `char`. For exemple, a number may look like this : `2 524,2`. Here, we have a "thousands" separator () and a "decimal" separator (`,`).

I try to convert these strings as double.

I know that I may do something like this :

```
double.Parse(str.Replace(tSep, '\0').Replace(dSep, '.'));
```

But I'm looking for a potential way of doing it more properly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `double.Parse()`or `double.TryParse()` you may create a special `CutureInfo` and set your separators there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double parse with culture format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109816/double-parse-with-culture-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
string s = "2 524,2";

CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(1);
NumberFormatInfo ni = new NumberFormatInfo();

ni.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
ni.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
ci.NumberFormat = ni;

decimal d = decimal.Parse(s, ci);
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing that I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
double.Parse(str.Replace(' ', '\0').Replace(',', '.'));
```

is fine, but you should also set the culture to `InvariantCulture`

```
double.Parse(str.Replace(' ', '\0').Replace(',', '.',
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

in order to be sure that your code will work on every user culture setting

Comment: [Don't use global state to manage a local problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx)

Comment: I have a preference for the other methode, even if this gives the same, but thank you for your answer.